# How do I modify existing XML data with powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a script that displays a GUI and helps in the process of setting up new PC's by uninstalling bloatware and installing common things like flash, java, browsers, etc, and a some other things. There are checkboxes and a few text boxes. I have included the ability to have "Presets" for certain customers. The presets are a drop down list, the name is chosen, and the boxes are automatically filled. The preset info currently sits in a CSV file, but I'm in the process of moving to XML. The script allows the user to create new presets and modify existing presets through a GUI window. To modify, all the desired options are chosen, the company to modify is chosen from a drop down and the user clicks "Save" to update the info in the file. This works well with CSV, however I can't figure out how to modify an existing preset in XML.

Here's a screenshot of the GUI box I'm referring to so it's easier to visualize.

[image]

The XML preset info looks like this...

```
<Customers>
<Name>Company Name</Name>
<Presets Option1="TRUE" Option2="TRUE" Option3="" Option4="TRUE" />

<Name>Company Name 2</Name>
<Presets Option1="" Option2="" Option3="TRUE" Option4="TRUE" />
</Customers>
```

and so on...

How do I take the checkbox and textbox info from the GUI and modify the preset data for a specific company?

I've been trying to use index numbers in a similar way that I do to populate the info into the GUI but I haven't had any luck.

Here's that index code...

```
$company = $companybox.SelectedItem
$indexname = $CustomersXML.Customers.Name
$index = [array]::IndexOf($indexname,$company)
If ($customersxml.customers.presets.Uninstall[$index] -eq "True") { $uninstallbox.checked = $True };
```

Comment: It would be simpler to select the presets for a named company if you change the XML format slightly i.e. to add a containing Customer element to contain Name and Presets i.e.
`<Customers>
  <Customer>
     <Name>blah</Name>
    <Presets ... />
  </Customer>
  ...
</Customers>`
then you could use XPath to select the Customer/Presets element where the Name matches the company name

Answer (score 0):

`$x = [xml]'<Customers><Customer><Name>one</Name><Presets A=""/></Customer><Customer><Name>two</Name><Presets A=""/></Customer></Customers>'
$customerName = 'one'
$x.SelectSingleNode('//Customer[Name = "' + $customerName + '"]/Presets').SetAttribute('A', 'newvalue2')`